# How to know when the scrollbar is on the far right side whith function scrollLeft()

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrollbar

When the scrollbar is on the far left side, the result of scrolleft() function is 0, but how I can know when the scrollbar is on the far right in this script for example?

http://jsfiddle.net/njKXB/84/

Thanks a lot!

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when the scroll bar is far right the scrollLeft() will be

```
document.getElementById('numeros').scrollWidth - document.getElementById('numeros').clientWidth;
```